# Detecting flooded areas using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have written a code to check if areas will be inundates when a certain value is added, the code doesn't give any errors but at the same time it doesn't do anything.

Just says running code complete, I am not even sure what the problem is.

My code is here:

```
import arcpy
import os, sys, traceback, shutil
import numpy as np

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

try:
     outputfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
     fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
     inputraster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

     #check to see if the arcinfo license is on
     if arcpy.CheckExtension("Spatial") == "Available":
          arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
     else:
          arcpy.AddError("Spatial analyst extension is not licensed.")
          sys.exit()

     #set the Progressor
     #arcpy.SetProgessor("step","Checking input requirements....",0,9,1) 

     #Process :create an out put folder
     arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(outputfolder,"output.gdb")
     outputgdb = outputfolder + "\\output.gdb"+ os.step

     #create path to store raster data
     clippedraster = outputfolder + "clippedraster"
     flooded = outputfolder +"floodedarea"

     #check to see if the inputs are in the same projection
     desccs_ras = arcpy.Describe(inputraster).SpatialReference
     desccs_fc = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference
     if desccs_ras.name == "Unknown" and desccs_fc.name == "Unknown":
          arcpy.AddMessage("Your data does not have a defined spatial reference")
     else:
          if desccs_ras.projectionName == desccs_fc.projectionName:
               ""
          else:
               arcpy.AddError("The input Data should be in the same projection")
               sys.exit()
          del desccs_fc,desccs_ras

     #remove the areas below sea level
     currentRaster = arcpy.Raster(inputraster)
     rastertoclip = Con(currentRaster>=0,currentRaster,1)

     #clip the raster data to the interested zone extend
     arcpy.Clip_management(rastertoclip,"#",clippedraster,fc,"#","ClippingGeometry","MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
     clip_raster = arcpy.Raster("in_memory")
     areasbelow = clip_raster <= 2
     areasbelow.save(flooded)

     md = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
     df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(md)[0]
     result = arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(flooded,"FloodedArea")
     layer = result.getOutput(0)
     arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

except:
     tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
     tbinfo = traceback.format_tb(tb)[0]
     pymsg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback Info:\n" + tbinfo + "\nError Info:\n    " + \
            str(sys.exc_type)+ ": " + str(sys.exc_value) + "\n"
```

Comment: It's very difficult for us to debug your code for you. Placing the entire code block in a `try-except` actually makes debugging harder. There's an awful lot of code here, when it looks like the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could be 10-15 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.step` is not anything. It will raise an attribute error. But `outputgdb` is never used anywhere else in the code anyway.

You don't see any errors because you use a try/except, but you never display the error. You create an error message (`pymsg`), but you don't do anything with it. So, your code will run up to `os.step` and then just end.

There may be subsequent errors in the code, but this is what you're currently seeing.

I suggest editing

```
outputgdb = outputfolder + "\\output.gdb"+ os.step
```

to read:

```
outputgdb = os.path.join(outputfolder, 'output.gdb')
arcpy.env.workspace = outputgdb
```

You should also remove the try/except, remove everything under 'except', and then dedent everything that was under 'try'. This way, you can actually read the details of the error. Alternatively, you could add the line...at the very end of the script, indented under 'except':

```
arcpy.AddError(pymsg)
```

This will ensure that your error message is printed to the ArcMap processing window for the tool.

If you're not in a toolbox (but it looks like you are), then just use:

```
print(pymsg)
```

Comment: the `os.step` is a typing error, yeah realized i wasn't printing the error message. thanks

Comment: yeah it was and I just marked it